# Xrdp hanging (Windows 10 to Xubuntu)

Tags: networking, xubuntu, windows, remote-desktop, xrdp

I have Xrdp installed and up-to-date on my Xubuntu machine and have opened up ports 3389 and 3350.
However, when I attempt to start a remote desktop session from my Windows 10 machine, the connection hangs on a blank blue screen after login.

After about 5 minutes the connection fials with the error below:

- connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
- sesman connect ok
- sending login info to session manager, please wait...
- login successful for display 10
- started connecting
- connection problem, giving up
- some problem

Xrdp was manually enabled, and all users logged out prior to remote session.
Both Xorg and X11rdp session types used with same results.

[Remote Session Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlNeJ.png)

**[EDIT] xrdp.ini** - This is my xrdp.ini file. I haven't made any changes

```
[Globals]
; xrdp.ini file version number
ini_version=1

; fork a new process for each incoming connection
fork=true
; tcp port to listen
port=3389
; 'port' above should be connected to with vsock instead of tcp
use_vsock=false
; regulate if the listening socket use socket option tcp_nodelay
; no buffering will be performed in the TCP stack
tcp_nodelay=true
; regulate if the listening socket use socket option keepalive
; if the network connection disappear without close messages the connection will be closed
tcp_keepalive=true
#tcp_send_buffer_bytes=32768
#tcp_recv_buffer_bytes=32768

; security layer can be 'tls', 'rdp' or 'negotiate'
; for client compatible layer
security_layer=negotiate
; minimum security level allowed for client
; can be 'none', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'fips'
crypt_level=high
; X.509 certificate and private key
; openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
certificate=
key_file=
; set SSL protocols
; can be comma separated list of 'SSLv3', 'TLSv1', 'TLSv1.1', 'TLSv1.2'
ssl_protocols=TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2
; set TLS cipher suites
#tls_ciphers=HIGH

; Section name to use for automatic login if the client sends username
; and password. If empty, the domain name sent by the client is used.
; If empty and no domain name is given, the first suitable section in
; this file will be used.
autorun=

allow_channels=true
allow_multimon=true
bitmap_cache=true
bitmap_compression=true
bulk_compression=true
#hidelogwindow=true
max_bpp=32
new_cursors=true
; fastpath - can be 'input', 'output', 'both', 'none'
use_fastpath=both
; when true, userid/password *must* be passed on cmd line
#require_credentials=true
; You can set the PAM error text in a gateway setup (MAX 256 chars)
#pamerrortxt=change your password according to policy at http://url

;
; colors used by windows in RGB format
;
blue=009cb5
grey=dedede
#black=000000
#dark_grey=808080
#blue=08246b
#dark_blue=08246b
#white=ffffff
#red=ff0000
#green=00ff00
#background=626c72

;
; configure login screen
;

; Login Screen Window Title
#ls_title=My Login Title

; top level window background color in RGB format
ls_top_window_bg_color=009cb5

; width and height of login screen
ls_width=350
ls_height=430

; login screen background color in RGB format
ls_bg_color=dedede

; optional background image filename (bmp format).
#ls_background_image=

; logo
; full path to bmp-file or file in shared folder
ls_logo_filename=
ls_logo_x_pos=55
ls_logo_y_pos=50

; for positioning labels such as username, password etc
ls_label_x_pos=30
ls_label_width=60

; for positioning text and combo boxes next to above labels
ls_input_x_pos=110
ls_input_width=210

; y pos for first label and combo box
ls_input_y_pos=220

; OK button
ls_btn_ok_x_pos=142
ls_btn_ok_y_pos=370
ls_btn_ok_width=85
ls_btn_ok_height=30

; Cancel button
ls_btn_cancel_x_pos=237
ls_btn_cancel_y_pos=370
ls_btn_cancel_width=85
ls_btn_cancel_height=30

[Logging]
LogFile=xrdp.log
LogLevel=DEBUG
EnableSyslog=true
SyslogLevel=DEBUG
; LogLevel and SysLogLevel could by any of: core, error, warning, info or debug

[Channels]
; Channel names not listed here will be blocked by XRDP.
; You can block any channel by setting its value to false.
; IMPORTANT! All channels are not supported in all use
; cases even if you set all values to true.
; You can override these settings on each session type
; These settings are only used if allow_channels=true
rdpdr=true
rdpsnd=true
drdynvc=true
cliprdr=true
rail=true
xrdpvr=true
tcutils=true

; for debugging xrdp, in section xrdp1, change port=-1 to this:
#port=/tmp/.xrdp/xrdp_display_10

; for debugging xrdp, add following line to section xrdp1
#chansrvport=/tmp/.xrdp/xrdp_chansrv_socket_7210


;
; Session types
;

; Some session types such as Xorg, X11rdp and Xvnc start a display server.
; Startup command-line parameters for the display server are configured
; in sesman.ini. See and configure also sesman.ini.
[Xorg]
name=Xorg
lib=libxup.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
code=20

[X11rdp]
name=X11rdp
lib=libxup.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
xserverbpp=24
code=10

[Xvnc]
name=Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
#xserverbpp=24
#delay_ms=2000

[console]
name=console
lib=libvnc.so
ip=127.0.0.1
port=5900
username=na
password=ask
#delay_ms=2000

[vnc-any]
name=vnc-any
lib=libvnc.so
ip=ask
port=ask5900
username=na
password=ask
#pamusername=asksame
#pampassword=asksame
#pamsessionmng=127.0.0.1
#delay_ms=2000

[sesman-any]
name=sesman-any
lib=libvnc.so
ip=ask
port=-1
username=ask
password=ask
#delay_ms=2000

[neutrinordp-any]
name=neutrinordp-any
lib=libxrdpneutrinordp.so
ip=ask
port=ask3389
username=ask
password=ask

; You can override the common channel settings for each session type
#channel.rdpdr=true
#channel.rdpsnd=true
#channel.drdynvc=true
#channel.cliprdr=true
#channel.rail=true
#channel.xrdpvr=true
```

Comment: You may have a similar situation to the following:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089373/xrdp-not-working-on-xubuntu-18-04-getting-vnc-error-1-after-security-negotiatio

Answer (score 1):

Anything activates the screen saver or lock screen seems to hang xrdp. This can be activated by timeout, or also certain key combinations: ctrl-alt-del (mapped from ctrl-alt-end by rdp

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the question at [Error/problem connecting (Windows 10 RDP into XRDP)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797973/error-problem-connecting-windows-10-rdp-into-xrdp)

The solution that helped me was running:

```
sudo apt-get remove xrdp vnc4server tightvncserver
sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
sudo apt-get install xrdp
sudo service xrdp restart
```

In fact in my case, I had only installed xrdp and completely forgot about tightvncserver. Not only do you have to include it, but it needs to be installed in the correct order.

If that doesn't fix your issue, could you post the contents of your xrdp.ini file? It is located at:

```
/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
```

In many cases, the default .ini file varies and causes some errors connecting.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have since tried your suggestion but has no effect. See EDIT in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

my comment was getting too long, so I'll add another answer.

I have had luck with changing the lines:

```
; can be comma separated list of 'SSLv3', 'TLSv1', 'TLSv1.1', 'TLSv1.2'
ssl_protocols=TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2
```

Try adjusting them to:

```
; can be comma separated list of 'SSLv3', 'TLSv1', 'TLSv1.1', 'TLSv1.2', 'TLSv1.3'
ssl_protocols=TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to have worked either. I have tried both your suggestion and some other combinations of TLS and SSL versions.
However, now the RDP session doesn't even connect to the computer